# Python Selenium Button click has no effect

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to download articles from Seeking Alpha. Since a lot of articles are only exclusive to subscribers, I have to sign in before viewing and downloading those articles. The code I used is provided as following. The problem I have is that the `click()` has no effect. When I manually signed in, it worked well.

```
# open website
url_lib = 'https://seekingalpha.com'
driver.get(url_lib)

# sign in
sign_in = driver.find_element_by_id('sign-in')
sign_in.click()

# id and pw
sign_id = driver.find_element_by_id('authentication_login_email')
sign_id.send_keys(Email address)
time.sleep(2)

sign_pw = driver.find_element_by_id('authentication_login_password')
sign_pw.send_keys(Password)
time.sleep(2)

# click submit button
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_id('log-btn')
submit_button.click()
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try `submit_button.submit()` instead of `submit_button.click()`?

Comment: @C.Peck It doesn't work...The reason may be that I was considered robot by the website since I actually got error in the "Console" ("failed to load resource: the server [...] responded with a status of 403") by using Webdriver. I think I need to figure out a way to bypass it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#sign-in"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control#authentication_login_email"))).send_keys("AnnieQW")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-control#authentication_login_password").send_keys("AnnieQW")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.orange-btn[value='Sign in']").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: seekingalpha]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! but it still doesn't work if you click "sign in" as I still get detected as robot. As long as the page is opened by webdriver, the website will consider you as a robot. I just have to go through all the "tests" and then get cleared...